# Count Even number in aLinkedList(java)

Tags: java, list, linked-list, counter

Q1- Consider a linked list implemented using the Node class below.
Implement the method:

```
public int countEvenNumbers(Node firstNode){} //This method counts the number of even numbers in the linked list
```

whose first node is firstNode. The implemented method shall be a recursive method. Here, firstNode references the first node in the linked list.

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int i){
        this(i, null);
    }

    Node(int i, Node n){
        data = i;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to implement it yourself? Read [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). SO is not code/homework writing service

Answer (score 2):

You can try it:

```
public int countEvenNumbers(Node node) {
    return countEventNumber(node, 0);
}

private int countEvenNumbers(Node node, int count) {
    if (node.data % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
    }
    if (node.next == null) {
        return count;
    }
    return countEvenNumbers(node.next, count);
}
```

Comment: i need to put a random numbers in a list and the method should show only the even number , so what i should write in the test class

Comment: @SaifYousif, that is a different question. You should not extend the question that you originally asked. If you cannot find a way to make the test code, then ask a new question that focuses on that, showing your efforts.